Htmx on custom events
I'm trying to use htmx triggers and custom events without success. I'm using custom events because I'm going to trigger multiple refresh in a page. My source is very simple, but I cannot make it work:
<html>
<script src="./js/htmx.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="detailDiv" hx-trigger="startProcessing" hx-get="/api/messages.php">GO</div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("startProcessing", () => {
    console.log("The startProcessing event was triggered")
});
htmx.trigger('#detailDiv','startProcessing')
</script>
</body>
</html>

HTMX is never triggered, and messages.php never called, while the javascript eventListener is correctly triggered. I do not understand why. Can you please post a full example of htmx reacting to javascript custom event?
I've lost so much time trying to figure out what the problem was.

Your code works, but I guess HTMX has not processed #detailDiv yet when the event is triggered (immediately when the <script> tag loads). Try waiting for the page to be fully loaded before triggering the event, as in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nyh8dtaj/ (see in the console how the request is sent upon running the fiddle)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    htmx.trigger('#detailDiv', 'startProcessing');
});


When working with HTMX and custom events, it’s crucial to ensure that HTMX is fully loaded before attempting to trigger them.

Ensure both DOM and HTMX are fully loaded, like:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="detailDiv" hx-trigger="startProcessing" hx-get="/api/messages.php">GO</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        document.addEventListener("startProcessing", () => {
            console.log("The startProcessing event was triggered");
        });
        htmx.trigger('#detailDiv', 'startProcessing');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>


Be aware because of htmx:onLoad() this code will cause an infinite loop if the HTMX request succeeds. The htmx:load event is fired not only when the page has finished loading, but also when HTMX loads anything. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q8kbstay/

@BenderBoy good catch, thank you!
